# error while using params in the router.push function vue-router 4

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

hello guys i'm new to vue js and i'm trying to pass paramenters to a specific router this should happen when i click on a card research and then it will redirect to the research details component called actions-log but when i call this router via

```
this.$router.push({ name: "actions-log", params: { Id: "3" } })
```

it gives me an error in the console says:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: No match for  {"name":"3","params":{}}

[image: my function that redirects from the research to the research details]

[image: the actions-log router]

[image: my index.js routes configurations]

[image: the error in the browser console]

so can any one help me with that error please......

Comment: That is how I do it, too. Weird is, that he thinks that "3" is the name. ... have not used params in capital. But I would not think, that it makes a difference.
... It could be the dash in actions-log. Sometime dashed names cause some errors in some places in Vue.

Comment: @Ehrlich_Bachman no not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out what's happening i have a component called pageTitle this component is included by every other component i use it to make the breadcrumb using the:

```
this.$route.fullPath
```

then spliting it and looping the values with :

```
<li><router-link></router-link></li>
```

to make the breadcrumbs links but the fullPath prop of the vue router it returns the params too so through the loop in:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: {path} }">{{ path }}</router-link>
```

vue checks if the router is exists with the given name, for example when i put /actions-log/3 as params int the url it will be set in the :to attribute becuase of this behavios it's launch that exception;

so i think i solved the problems in the following computed fuction :
[image: function to get the full path then split it and uses the values to create a breadCrumbs]

[image: the loop in the template]

i don't know if someone has a better idea to create a breadCrumbs in vue...
anyway thank you so much for helping me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code.

Comment: @Joosep.P why is that ?

Comment: @nerween https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `path`

```
const routeId = 3

this.$router.push({ path: `/actions-log/${routeId}` })
```

Comment: nothing changes, it gives me the exact same error the rare thing is even when i put the link http://localhost:8080/actions-log/3 int the url tab it shows the same error.